# ASP.NET MVC datetime editor

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC and I want to create editor for date and time.

Here is the part of my model

```
[Display(Name = "Activity Date")]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime activityDate { get; set; }
```

and part of my view

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.activityDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "dateTimePicker form-control" } })
```

Now when I am trying to edit this field data is just a string, but if I change model like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Activity Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]//changed line
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime activityDate { get; set; }
```

The editor becomes fancy with ability to change values by mouse wheel scrolling and a well designed datePicker, but with out ability to set time.

Can I get both fancy look and UI and ability to change time?

i tried to use this [datetime picker for jquery](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).
Here is my html that i get rendered in browser

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Activity Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Activity Date field is required." id="datetimepicker" name="activityDate" type="datetime" value="2015-01-14 12:00">
```

and this is part of my View

```
<script>jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();</script>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dateTimePicker")
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/dateTimePicker1")`
```

but it slill doesn't work.

Comment: You are decorating the element with `dateTimePicker` - this appears to be a plugin that allows the ability to select dates.  I would start by checking the plugin documentation, or expand your question to include the plugin information.

Comment: i thought that it's part of jQuery,so i tried to add this, but it doesn't help,deleting this part changes nothing.

Comment: @Alex Though I am not sure which dateTimePicker you are using, but if you have included [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) on your page, you can try [this](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order, and add `document.ready`. Not:

```
<script>jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();</script>
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dateTimePicker")
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/dateTimePicker1")`
```

But:

```
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dateTimePicker")
}
@Styles.Render("~/Content/dateTimePicker1")`
// type='text/javascript' will allow to work it in IE7
<script type="text/javascript">
   // that will help you to be sure that script will execute just when document is ready
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
   })
</script>
```

Comment: thank you,it helped.
but i added script to file and than added file to bundle.

Comment: Yeap, using scripts inside views is not the best way, better to hold in separate files. I just wrote to show how to fix your problem and what is the reason.